# JS HighCharts.js Pie data in different format

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and I started with this code for a pie chart which works fine:

```
//THE DATA:
var data = [{ name: 'Name 1', y: 20, id: 0 },{ name: 'Name 2', y: 10, id: 1 },{ name: 'Name 3', y: 10, id: 2 }];


//THE CHART CODE:
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

   series:[
      {
         "data": data,
          type: 'pie',
          animation: false,
          point:{
              events:{
                  click: function (event) {
                      //alert(this.id);
                  }


              }
          }          
      }
   ],
   "chart":{
      "renderTo":"container"
   },
});

//The above with create a pie chart with 3 names
```

The issue I have starts below because I have been given the data that is needs to read in a different format

```
//The Data

var mydata =[{

    "001":{

        "name":"Name 1",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":2
        }

    },
    "002":{

        "name":"Name 2",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":20
        }

    },


}];
```

How can I get the data I have above to work with the pie chart?

Comment: I think that you need to format it a little bit for format accepted by Highcharts. Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/84qd2xp6/

Comment: Tried this: var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
  var obj = mydata[i];      
  var newObj = {      
         name: obj[i].name,
          y: obj[i].subhere.subhere1,
          id: i       };
data.push(newObj);      
} from SrAxi answer but I'm getting "name" is not defined

Comment: Have you tried my example?

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting error: "name" is not defined

Comment: So maybe not all of your data have name parameter? Or maybe your output is not in the format provided by you?

Comment: Yes, the code and data I'm using for the test is exactly what's above in my question

Comment: I know where the problem is: If I add console.log(mydata[i]); ... I get the listing but it starts with 001.... so mydata[i].name would be undefined because the object starts with 001 or 002 as the parent. The problem is that I need the code to get the 001 or 002 dynamically just like [i] does. How can I sort this problem?

Comment: I have used your data and it is working in my case: http://jsfiddle.net/84qd2xp6/ Please post the whole code that you are trying to use right now and I will try to find mistakes inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reformat the data given to you the same way as the `data[]` that worked for you in the Highchart.

Try this:

```
var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {       //looping through data received
        var obj = mydata[i];      //current obj in loop
        var newObj = {      //creating new obj with same structure as the 'data' that works
            name: obj.name,
            y: obj.subhere.subhere1,
            id: i       
        };

        data.push(newObj);      //pushing each object into the data array
    }
```

Let me know how it goes! I hope it helped, good luck!

Comment: Getting error: TypeError: obj[i] is undefined
 name: obj[i].name,

Comment: @gafasmill Oh! Try with `obj.name`

Comment: @gafasmill I have just edited my answer. Check it now, and see if it works.

Comment: Tried your edited answer ... almost there now but getting this error: TypeError: obj.subhere is undefined y: obj.subhere.subhere1,

Comment: @gafasmill I typed `obj.subhere.subhere1` because I wrote my answer based on the `mydata[]` object that you said you were receiving. Check the object that you are receiving if it actually has those names. 
And anyhow, try debugging with Firebug on Mozilla Firefox. So you can see exactly what is happening. From here is hard for me to help you without being able to debug and test the code myself...

Comment: Anyhow, I believe that the question was to transform the data from one format, `mydata[]`, to another format that suits Highcharts, the original `data[]` that you put at the beginning of your post.
And that, I think I answered. 
As soon as you solve the naming issue you should be good to go. I hope you can do it easily! Let me know! ;)

Comment: I'm using exactly the data / myData posted here so y: obj.subhere.subhere1, should work because the names are actually there so I don't get why it's not working :-/